# Spring webflux how to share data from Controller to Filter using Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In controller I need to share some data to WebFilter (I don't want to use `ServerWebExchange.getAttributes().put("KEY", "VALUE")`, and my boss either), this is my current implemetation:

```
@Component
public class RequestFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> Mono.deferWithContext(c -> {
      //I CHECK WHETHER DATA SHARED FROM CONTROLLER EXIST OR NOT
      System.out.println(c.hasKey("abc"));
      Context innerContext = c.get("CONTEXT");
      System.out.println(innerContext.hasKey("abc"));
      return Mono.empty();
    }));

    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
    BodyCaptureExchange bodyCaptureExchange = new BodyCaptureExchange(exchange);

    return chain.filter(bodyCaptureExchange).subscriberContext(context -> {
      //HERE I PUT CONTEXT TO ITSELF
      context = context.put("CONTEXT", context);
      return context;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> post(@RequestBody Mono<Request> request) {
    Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> responseEntityMono = request.flatMap(
            rq -> service.requestProcess(rq).map(res -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(res))
        ).subscriberContext(c -> {
            //HERE I GET THE INNER CONTEXT FROM ABOVE FILTER
            Context innerContext = c.get("CONTEXT");
            //PUT DATA TO IT
            c = c.put("CONTEXT", innerContext.put("abc", "abc"));
            //ALSO PUT DATA TO PARENT
            c = c.put("abc", "abc");
            return c;
        });
        
    return responseEntityMono;
}
```

The System.out.println in RequestFilter print:

```
false
false
```

Means that data I put from controller are lost when it come to Filter. I stuck here almost 2 days. Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. I really need your help

Reactor version: 3.3.14

Spring boot stater webflux: 2.3.9.RELEASE

Comment: Context extension works downstream, not upstream, like variable scopes in programming. Where exit from scope context will be removed. So, that leaves you with what you don't want. Or search for another solution design.

Comment: It is not removed, it still there but somehow my values are lost

Comment: Not removed and values are lost. Am I the only one feeling conflicted? :)

Comment: Upload a PoC code into GitHub and I will check it.